# Android Mapping between 2D Array and Grid

Tags: android

I am trying to make a Chess like game in Android which involves 8 X 8 grid. I also have a 8 x 8 two dimensional matrix in the back end and some 64 buttons( 8 X 8) in front end.

My question is that I want one on one correspondence for this matrix and buttons ie.
(a) when I press a button I want to get (i,j) so that I can refer to corresponding matrix entry and

(b) when I have (i,j) values from matrix I can figure out the button to perform some action.

I cant figure out how to map them both. suggestions please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the view's tag.  Its a place to put any metadata you want.  Set the tag to an integer value 0-63.  The value/8 is the row, tha vale%8 is the column.  You can get and set the tag via `getTag()` and `setTag()`.

For the reverse mapping, have a second matrix of view objects.  Or have 1 matrix of a class with the view for that space and the original data you had in that spot.